# Nullability warning for a field instatiated in Setup, BenchmarkDotNet

Tags: c#, .net, benchmarkdotnet

The field `_requestSigner2` is giving the nullability warning. It's basically instatiated in `Setup()`, which is the normal routine in BenchmarkDotNet but Visual Studio doesn't know that. What is the recommended way to solve that? `= null!`?

```cs
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class RequestSignerBenchmarks
{
    private RequestSigner2 _requestSigner2;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _requestSigner2 = RequestSigner2.FromSecret("aGlkZGVu");
    }

    [GlobalCleanup]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        _requestSigner2.Dispose();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void First()
    {
        var timestamp = TimestampProvider.Default.CurrentTimestamp();
        _requestSigner2.Sign(timestamp, "GET", "products", "");
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void Second()
    {
        var signer = RequestSigner.FromSecret("aGlkZGVu");

        var timestamp = TimestampProvider.Default.CurrentTimestamp();
        signer.Sign(timestamp, "GET", "products", "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would just create a static field in this case (since you don't have complex/parameter depended initialization logic):

```cs
public class RequestSignerBenchmarks
{
    private static RequestSigner2 _requestSigner2 = RequestSigner2.FromSecret("aGlkZGVu");
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `= null!` is indeed a good way to deal with this warning.
But I suggest you have all benchmarks separated or identified somehow to disable them in rules using pattern matching.

Example:

`[*.bench.cs]` or `[*/Benchmarks/*.cs]`

./.editorconfig

```
[*/Benchmarks/*.bench.cs]

# CS8618: Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
dotnet_diagnostic.CS8618.severity = none
```